# What's the difference between "add to network" and "connect" in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

What's the difference between "add to network" and "connect" in "People You May Know"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Add to network" are taken from your contacts list or address book (if you've allowed LinkedIn to see that), but do not yet have a matching LinkedIn account. For these you will see the name, but instead of a job title, it will list their email address.

"Connect" will appear for existing LinkedIn profiles.

When you click "Add to network" [it will send an invite to the person](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29/h/c) (but will not be customisable) asking them to join and create an account.

Comment: Thanks. [Can I hide the “add to network” proposals in LinkedIn's People You May Know page?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54927/18147)

Comment: There must be something else going on though, because it is showing me people with the "add to network" link and saying that we have a shared connection

Comment: in fact, in the screenshot in the question above, there is someone with "add to network", and two shared contacts

Comment: They may still not have accounts, as they may have also been found in other users' address books @sou

Comment: I'm also seeing “**Invite to LinkedIn**” buttons under some names in the current rev of LinkedIn, so I don't believe your explanation for “**Add to network**” is still accurate.