# How can I hide the “add to network” proposals in LinkedIn's People You May Know page?

Tags: linkedin

When I click on "Add to network" [it will send an invite to the person](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29/h/c) (but will not be customisable) asking them to join and create an account.

I don't want this. How can I hide the “add to network”  proposals in LinkedIn's People You May Know page?

[image]

Comment: Can you see these people in your LinkedIn contacts area? http://www.linkedin.com/people/contacts?sortAction=lastName&showInvited=true&membersOnly=false&trk=ac-manage-contacts

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Yes

Comment: Does deleting them from your contacts also remove them from suggestions?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Yes it seems so. But I have around 2,500 imported contacts, it is unhandy to do this manually as I don't want to remove all imported contacts since some of them are existing LinkedIn contacts :/